# Two exponential distributions

Tags: r, statistics, exponential-distribution

I am trying to simulate two exponential distributions. For example two CPUs processing jobs e.g. one having average service time 10 min (lambda = 0.1) and another one 20 min (lambda = 0.05) and they work independently. Both of them are busy when a new job arrives.

I would like to simulate the waiting time of a new job

Here is what I did so far.

```
cpu1 = rexp(n = 10000, rate = .1)
cpu2 = rexp(n = 10000, rate = .05)
```

I generate 10K data points based on exponential distribution. For each of them new job has to wait `min(cpu1[i], cpu2[i])` I store all of them in a data frame and compute the mean.

```
for (i in seq(1, 10000)) {
    if (i == 1) {
       df1 <- data.frame(waiting_time=min(cpu1[i], cpu2[i])) 
    } else {
       df1 <- rbind(df1, data.frame(waiting_time=data.frame(waiting_time=min(cpu1[i], cpu2[i])))
    }
}
mean(df1$waiting_time)
```

Is this the right way to do the simulation? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `mean(pmin(cpu1,cpu2))` is equivalent to the `for` loop and `mean(df1$waiting_time)`, but much, much faster.

Or you could skip the simulation altogether since the minimum of two independent random exponential variables is also exponentially distributed with a rate equal to the sum of the two rates. Furthermore, the sum of `n` iid exponential random variables is gamma-distributed with the same rate parameter and a shape parameter equal to `n`.

So we can simply do `rgamma(1, 1e4, 0.15)/1e4` or, equivalently, `rgamma(1, 1e4, 0.15*1e4)` instead of `mean(pmin(cpu1,cpu2))`, and the results will have identical distributions.

Answer (score 0):

The simulation is already done, by your definitions. You are asking how to compute the final results, which can be done with `mean(pmin(cpu1,cpu2))`.

Comment: my question is whether `min(cpu1[i], cpu2[i])` inside the loop is correct simulation of the problem described. In other words - is it a true representation of the waiting time of the new job that arrives?

Comment: @user3138594 If you define the waiting time as the minimum waiting time between cpu1 and cpu2, which are independent, then yes, that is correct.